# Having issue with in-app purchases promotions on the app store

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have submitted an in-App purchase item for app store promotion, everything approved and fine, But there is a yellow box with this warning:

> These in-app purchases can’t be promoted on the App Store because your
>   latest approved binary doesn’t include the
>   SKPaymentTransactionObserver method.

I am sure I have added `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` method in my code, for making sure I have added in two places one in `IAPManager` class and another in main `ViewController`!.

[image]

How should I fix this issue? 
The source code is available in this [**tutorial**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1458378-in-app-purchase-tutorial-auto-renewable-subscriptions)

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672653/skpaymenttransactionobserver-in-app-purchases-can-t-be-promoted-on-the-app-stor, the problem could be in iTunes connect side, try to create a radar ticker for it

Comment: I used SwiftyStoreKit and fixed my issue.

Comment: Good to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

An in-app purchase cannot be promoted in AppStoreConnect until the version of the app containing the additional ‘purchase from app store’ function has completed the Apple App Review process successfully.
The app containing this extra function needs to be either live on the App Store or Pending Developer Release (my preferred choice) before it is possible to promote an in app purchase and the message in the yellow box you are seeing is removed.
Can you confirm the status of your app in the App Review process?